# Bluetooth connectivity using IOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Hi i just want to clarify few things after i went through all the details by googling whole day.

**Firstly** i want to know Can we list all the devices**(including Android,blackberry etc)**using bluetooth connectivity in our ios device?

If **yes** how do we do??Once listing out the device can we able to connect to it**(including Android,blackberry etc)** ?According to my knowledge we cant connect to any other device using bluetooth as apple wont support.But is there any way can we connect it?Just for my knowledge purpose.

**Secondly** i went through framework called **BluetoothManager** where i saw a sample code where it displays a list of devices when bluetooth is ON, but i didnt see **IOS devices** listing when we use **Bluetooth Manager**.

So can anyone tel me For what exactly Bluetooth manager is used for  and can we connect with ios device to any other Devices and tranfer files using this Framework?Is it possible?

I know about Gamkekit Framework where it is used to connect between two or more IOS devices.
But i am eager to know Other than Gamekit there are any other way where we can connect to other devices using bluetooth.

Please anyone would tel me regarding would be very helpfull for me and others as well.Looking forward to for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three frameworks available in iOS using which you can develop the bluetooth applications:

1. **GameKit**: This is the publicly available framework . But using this you can only establish and communicate between only two iOS device. So this framework having its own limitations .
2. **BluetoothManager**: This is private framework .I used this framework to discover the non iOS devices . I have established the connection also . But cant able to do the data exchange. I think it is still under development. For the reference you can refer this link
3. **CoreBluetooth**: This is also the public framework. This can only discover BLE enabled devices . I have successfully used this to transfer the data between the BLE enabled devices.

Comment: This is same answer which is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580096/android-ios-direct-communication-bluetooth-is-it-possible  but i want to know bit more.

Comment: using corebluetooth if check this link  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html that app how do it works??

Comment: i mean can we transfer files between two devices???in the Temperature sensor how do we connect between two devices because when i load i didnt find to connect with devices and also want to know whether we can transfer files or any text between two devices using  CoreBluetooth or  Bluetooth manager

Comment: yes you can transfer text from one application to another . But for checking those you have to have two instance of your application that will run on the two different devices .one in central mode one in the peripheral mode . central will scan for the peripheral devices . I havent check that temperature application but you can have a look at the http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html that I have referred  while creating the application using the BLE.

Comment: so devices can be any..including Android devices???so for this the application should be running on both the devices then only we can connect???but it can be any device???

Comment: yeah , you can use any device as a peripheral provided that it should be BLE enabled .

Comment: ok thanks alot...so all the devices doesnt have BLE rite like android and all ios devices doesnt have BLE...

Comment: No , only http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Bluetooth-Smart-Devices-List.aspx  this much devices have BLE enable .

Comment: I have a device **"socketMobile"** Sensor of barcodes. This device not appear in list when i implemented CoreBluetooth option. How i know when a device is BLE or an Common Bluetooth?.                                                                            Later i implemented the BluetoothManager.framework and this works correctly, But when i try compile, xcode (or itunnes connect) show problems because this is a private library. I need other solution please.. Thanks