# Implementing an Bluetooth functionality in IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-location, ios-bluetooth

Based in this question.
[Bluetooth connectivity using IOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957909/bluetooth-connectivity-using-ios-device?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I use the same options. Is exactly my case.

I have a device "socketMobile" Sensor of barcodes. This device not appear in list when i implemented CoreBluetooth option. How i know when a device is BLE or an Common Bluetooth?. Later i implemented the BluetoothManager.framework and this works correctly, But when i try compile, xcode (or itunnes connect) show problems because this is a private library. I need other solution please.. Thanks –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically: devices that are BTLE will commonly be branded with Bluetooth LE or Bluetooth Smart (and occasionally Bluetooth 4.0).

Specifically, since you incorporated the classic Bluetooth framework and your device was found, it's a pretty clear indicator that it's classic Bluetooth and you will need to become a part of Apple's MFi program in order to reach external accessories. Commonly, device manufacturers who have APIs also have a method for you to use their code without formally having to join Apple's program, but that's a case by case basis and you'd need to contact the vendor to see what their approach is, if any.

Comment: Thanks i found the ScanAPI_SDK_iOS for this socketMobile scanners.