# Communication over wifi or wirless access points in iOS device

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am looking for making my app compatible with wifi in the same infrastructure. So is there any SDK that can support bi-directional communication without internet, we assume that devices will be placed  closed to each other.

Regards,
Aamir

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html):

> The Multipeer Connectivity framework provides support for discovering
>   services provided by nearby iOS devices using infrastructure Wi-Fi
>   networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth personal area networks and
>   subsequently communicating with those services by sending
>   message-based data, streaming data, and resources (such as files).

[This SO answer directly addresses your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580096/android-ios-direct-communication-bluetooth-is-it-possible)